# sql string execute without prepared statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to run a prepared statement, but I am encountering with a error.

Here's my query:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=4294967295;
SET @SQL = NULL;
SET @start_date = '2018-06-03';
SET @end_date = '2018-06-09';

    SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
        'SUM(CASE WHEN date = "',DATE(issuedDateTime),'" THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) AS `',DATE(issuedDateTime),'`'
        )
    ) INTO @SQL

        FROM `lunch_status` 
        WHERE DATE(issuedDateTime) BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date;

    SET @SQL 
    = CONCAT('SELECT userId, ', @SQL, ' 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT userId, lunchStatus, DATE(issuedDateTime) as date 
        FROM `lunch_status` 
        WHERE DATE(issuedDateTime) BETWEEN "',@start_date,'" AND "',@end_date,'" 
    ) as a
    GROUP BY userId;');

SELECT @SQL; /* executing upto this part, SQL variable stores expected query string.

/* including this part, gives error . */
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This SQL variable is giving the desired query string:

```
SELECT userId, 
SUM(CASE WHEN date = "2018-06-03" THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) AS `2018-06-03`,
SUM(CASE WHEN date = "2018-06-04" THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) AS `2018-06-04`,
SUM(CASE WHEN date = "2018-06-06" THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) AS `2018-06-06`,
SUM(CASE WHEN date = "2018-06-07" THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) AS `2018-06-07`,
SUM(CASE WHEN date = "2018-06-08" THEN lunchStatus ELSE 0 END) AS `2018-06-08` 
   FROM
   (
       SELECT userId, lunchStatus, DATE(issuedDateTime) as date 
       FROM `lunch_status` 
       WHERE DATE(issuedDateTime) BETWEEN "2018-06-03" AND "2018-06-09" 
   ) as a
   GROUP BY userId;
```

If run this query separately, it is producing the expected result-set.

But when trying to execute it as a Prepared Statement, it is giving an error.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getClauses() on null in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Utils\Query.php:564 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Utils\Query.php(681): PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Utils\Query::getClause(NULL, NULL, 'ORDER BY', -1, false) #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\DisplayResults.php(1385): PhpMyAdmin\SqlParser\Utils\Query::replaceClause(NULL, NULL, 'ORDER BY', '') #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\DisplayResults.php(4376): PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getUnsortedSqlAndSortByKeyDropDown(Array, '') #3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sql.lib.php(1689): PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->getTable(Object(mysqli_result), Array, Array, false) #4 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sql.lib.php(1980): PMA_getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(Object(PMA\libraries\DisplayResults), './themes/pmahom...', NULL, Array, false, 122, 122, NULL, Object(mysqli_result), Array) #5 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sql.lib.php(2199): PMA_getQueryResponseForResultsReturned(Objec in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Utils\Query.php on line 564
```

Is there any other way to execute this String variable directly without using prepared statement?

Comment: If you use php anyway, then transfer the logic into php.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I checked it.. doesn't matter be it double-quotes or single-quote

Comment: Which version do you use? **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e3f2dfe9cf59d48ddf2df2b9fa90e12c)** I suggest to wrap it with stored procedure and call stored procedure from PHP

Comment: 10.1.26-MariaDB.. Yeah I'm trying to do the same.